# How could I use Euclidean Distance formula to calculate the heuristic here? and make the algorithm searches in eight directions?

Tags: python, path-finding, a-star, heuristics

I'm working on A star algorithm and I set my heuristic as below :

```
heuristic = [[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4],
             [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3],
             [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2],
             [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
             [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]]
```

And the movement of the algorithm just for four directions as below:

```
delta = [[-1, 0 ], # go up
         [ 0, -1], # go left
         [ 1, 0 ], # go down
         [ 0, 1 ]] # go right    
delta_name = ['^','<','V','>']
```

and the output of my algorithm like this:

```
[11, 11, 0, 4, 5]
############## Search is success
[0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
[1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
[2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
[3, -1, 8, 9, 10, 11]
[4, 5, 6, 7, -1, 12]

['V', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['V', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['V', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['V', ' ', ' ', '>', '>', 'V']
['>', '>', '>', '^', ' ', '*']
```

How could I calculate the heuristic by Euclidean Distance formula and make the algorithm moves in eight directions, not just four?.

This is my code:

```
import random
grid = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
heuristic = [[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4],
             [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3],
             [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2],
             [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
             [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]]
init = [0,0]                           
goal = [len(grid)-1,len(grid[0])-1]
#Below the four potential actions to the single field
delta = [[-1 , 0],   #up 
         [ 0 ,-1],   #left
         [ 1 , 0],   #down
         [ 0 , 1]]   #right

delta_name = ['^','<','V','>']  #The name of above actions
cost = 1
def search():
    #open list elements are of the type [g,x,y]
    closed = [[0 for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]
    action = [[-1 for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]

    #We initialize the starting location as checked
    closed[init[0]][init[1]] = 1
    expand=[[-1 for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]

    # we assigned the cordinates and g value
    x = init[0]
    y = init[1]
    g = 0
    h = heuristic[x][y]
    f = g + h 

    #our open list will contain our initial value
    open = [[f, g, h, x, y]]
    found  = False   #flag that is set when search complete
    resign = False   #Flag set if we can't find expand
    count = 0

    #print('initial open list:')
    #for i in range(len(open)):
            #print('  ', open[i])
    #print('----')

    while found is False and resign is False:    
        #Check if we still have elements in the open list
        if len(open) == 0:    #If our open list is empty, there is nothing to expand.
            resign = True
            print('Fail')
            print('############# Search terminated without success')
            print()
        else: 
            #if there is still elements on our list
            #remove node from list
            open.sort()             #sort elements in an increasing order from the smallest g value up
            open.reverse()          #reverse the list
            next = open.pop()       #remove the element with the smallest g value from the list
            #print('list item')
            #print('next')

            #Then we assign the three values to x,y and g. Which is our expantion.
            x = next[3]
            y = next[4]
            g = next[1]

            expand[x][y] = count
            count+=1

            #Check if we are done
            if x == goal[0] and y == goal[1]:
                found = True
                print(next) #The three elements above this "if".
                print('############## Search is success')
                print()

            else:
                #expand winning element and add to new open list
                for i in range(len(delta)):       #going through all our actions the four actions
                    #We apply the actions to x and y with additional delta to construct x2 and y2
                    x2 = x + delta[i][0]
                    y2 = y + delta[i][1]

                    #if x2 and y2 falls into the grid
                    if x2 >= 0 and x2 < len(grid) and y2 >=0 and y2 <= len(grid[0])-1:

                        if closed[x2][y2] == 0 and grid[x2][y2] == 0:
                            g2 = g + cost            
                            h2 = heuristic[x2][y2]
                            f2 = g2 + h2 

                            open.append([f2,g2,h2,x2,y2])   
                            #print('append list item')
                            #print([g2,x2,y2])
                            #Then we check them to never expand again
                            closed[x2][y2] = 1
                            action[x2][y2] = i

    for i in range(len(expand)):
        print(expand[i])
    print()

    policy=[[' ' for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]
    x=goal[0]
    y=goal[1]
    policy[x][y]='*'
    while x !=init[0] or y !=init[1]:
        x2=x-delta[action[x][y]][0]
        y2=y-delta[action[x][y]][1]
        policy[x2][y2]= delta_name[action[x][y]]
        x=x2
        y=y2
    for i in range(len(policy)):
        print(policy[i])

search()
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a graph: https://networkx.github.io/ ?

Comment: @Dan To be honest with you dear, this is the first time I know, there is something like this beside Matplotlib.

Comment: no a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)), not a plot. the algorithm finds the shortest route connecting two nodes on a graph. So at the moment, your graph has edges between up-down and left-right neighbours. To get diagonal movement, you wouldn't change the algorithm, you would just add connections (edges) into your graph.

Comment: @Dan Could you help me in this matter, sir? I feel confused.. How could I manage it?.

Comment: That's a bit too open ended, take a look at this https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.astar.astar_path.html. Also maybe https://www.coursera.org/lecture/algorithms-graphs-data-structures/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-rxrPa

Comment: @Dan Thank you so much dear. I'll check them